# error responce 401 in twitter api in iphone

Tags: twitter

I am integrating api in my application. when I am trying to tweet I am getting an error request 401, it seems to "Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect". How will I remove this error ?

Thanks

Comment: You've presented too little info; posting the code for your authentication attempt would be helpful.